# Inputing the file path and file name which you are working in Vim

Tags: vim

I use `Ctrl-G` to see the path. But I want to enter the path to the file itself.

How can I achieve this in Vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the current file is contained in the `%` register. See

```
:help quote%
```

You can insert the contents of that register as you would any other register, e.g.,

```
"%p
"%P
:put %
```

and in insert mode as

```
<C-R>%
```

where `<C-R>` means `Ctrl-R`.

You can also expand the file name to its full path and select various parts of the path or file name using `expand()` and file name modifiers. See

```
:help expand()
:help filename-modifiers
```

As an example, while in insert mode, you could type

```
<C-R>=expand("%:p")
```

followed by `Enter`, where again `<C-R>` means `Ctrl-R`, which would insert the full path name of the current file. See

```
:help i_CTRL-R_=
```